# String encryption with salt of fixed length

Tags: php, encryption

I need to create a password generation method where user passes in a string and gets a password encrypted using the SALT.
When the user keys in the same string they get the same password.

```
<?php

$textToEncrypt = "String passed by user";
$encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC"; 
$secretHash = "25c6c7ff35b9979bdsfdsgsdfsdf";

//To encrypt
$encryptedMessage = openssl_encrypt($textToEncrypt, $encryptionMethod, $secretHash);

//To Decrypt
$decryptedMessage = openssl_decrypt($encryptedMessage, $encryptionMethod, $secretHash);

//Result
echo "Encrypted: $encryptedMessage\n";
echo "Decrypted: $decryptedMessage\n";
```

I need to have a the password of length 16 or 10 and have an option of alphanumeric and or special character parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using an existing method for it.  If you roll your own, there are many ways to make it cryptographically insecure by mistake (in this case, especially by timing or power differential attack which are unlikely but still).  Here is a method that looks right for what you are asking:

```
string hash_pbkdf2 ( string $algo , string $password , string $salt , int $iterations [, int $length = 0 [, bool $raw_output = false ]] )
```

And here is the whole [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php)

Comment: Thanks, that will do.